# Terraform: How to make sure I run terraform on the expected AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Suppose I want to launch an EC2 instance in my dev account but it is possible that I accidentally run the wrong command and create a temporary credential of prod account instead of dev account, then when I Terraform apply, I will launch the EC2 at prod account?

How can I avoid this from happening? Can I create a text file with dev account id in this folder, then have Terraform compare the account id of my temporary credential with the account id in this file before launching EC2, maybe in null_resource? I cannot figure out how to implement that.

Comment: Use automation for your production account and limit the dispensing of credentials. Ideally, you should never have production credentials on your own PC.

Comment: jarmod. Thanks, how to automation? how can I create a script to verify the account id of the temporary credential = the account id in the txt file before terraform continues?

Comment: You should try to avoid ever being in this situation. However, if you absolutely need to know which account a given set of credentials relate to then use the awscli: aws sts get-caller-identity (or its SDK equivalent). That will tell you the AWS account number associated with the credentials.

Comment: jamod, I do know the variable "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}", but if I terraform apply, I am afraid the ec2 has been launched before the variable is compared with the txt file. how to have it  compare with the txt file before ec2 is launched?

Comment: jamod. I read your command again. I think I understand now.create a script, which run aws cli before terraform apply. that is a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Right. You could also apply a policy to the production IAM credentials that require the use of MFA. That way you could not accidentally use them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The AWS provider allows you to specify either a list of [`allowed_account_ids`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#allowed_account_ids) or a list of [`forbidden_account_ids`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#forbidden_account_ids) that you could define to prevent that from happening if necessary.

So you might have a folder structure that looks a little like this:

```
$ tree -a
.
├── dev
│   ├── bar-app
│   │   ├── dev-eu-west-1.tf -> ../../providers/dev-eu-west-1.tf
│   │   └── main.tf
│   ├── foo-app
│   │   ├── dev-eu-west-1.tf -> ../../providers/dev-eu-west-1.tf
│   │   └── main.tf
│   └── vpc
│       ├── dev-eu-west-1.tf -> ../../providers/dev-eu-west-1.tf
│       └── main.tf
├── prod
│   ├── bar-app
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   └── prod-eu-west-1.tf -> ../../providers/prod-eu-west-1.tf
│   ├── foo-app
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   └── prod-eu-west-1.tf -> ../../providers/prod-eu-west-1.tf
│   └── vpc
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── prod-eu-west-1.tf -> ../../providers/prod-eu-west-1.tf
├── providers
│   ├── dev-eu-west-1.tf
│   ├── prod-eu-west-1.tf
│   └── test-eu-west-1.tf
└── test
    ├── bar-app
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   └── test-eu-west-1.tf -> ../../providers/test-eu-west-1.tf
    ├── foo-app
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   └── test-eu-west-1.tf -> ../../providers/test-eu-west-1.tf
    └── vpc
        ├── main.tf
        └── test-eu-west-1.tf -> ../../providers/test-eu-west-1.tf
```

Where your `providers/dev-eu-west-1.tf` file looks like:

```
provider "aws" {
  region              = "eu-west-1"
  allowed_account_ids = [
    "1234567890",
  ]
}
```

And your `providers/test-eu-west-1.tf` file looks like:

```
provider "aws" {
  region              = "eu-west-1"
  allowed_account_ids = [
    "5678901234",
  ]
}
```

This would mean that you could only run Terraform against `dev/foo-app` when you are using credentials belonging to the `1234567890` account and could only run Terraform against `dev/foo-app` when you are using credentials belonging to the `5678901234` account.

Comment: Thanks ydaetskcoR, this exactly answers my question!

Comment: This is nice, but is there a way that this can be done without hardcoding the accountid into a file?  Ideally I'd like to check against the currently used AWS_PROFILE.

Comment: @monkut the idea is that you want to verify that current aws profile is for an account that is allowed to run terraform apply on that stack.

Comment: WARNING: If this is an empty list everything is allowed. So define your fallback variable to something like allowed_account_ids = ["DUMMY"] to prevent accidental provisions

Answer (score 3):

Store your terraform state in an S3 bucket for that account.  Make sure the buckets are named uniquely (they have to be unique to a region anyway). If you run it against the wrong account, it will error out because the bucket cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks myron-semack this is also a good answer. in fact if I store terraform state in remote s3, it will be impossible for me to apply wrong account (say dev account) to right account (say prod account) because dev account has no access permission to the remote s3 bucket of prod account. But I have to vote ydaetskcoR's answer because his answer exactly answers my question, it works even I do not use remote s3 to store state file.

Comment: It's a nice trick, but it's not necessarily easy to set up when you inherit from a legacy project without any documentation and you need to be absolutely sure that all this spaghetti code won't destroy resources on the Production account. Using "allowed_account_ids" makes you certain that this legacy code that you're playing with won't impact anything of importance while testing things out in order to understand how everything works.